# AWS lambda error message when importing mysql2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, import, mysql2

I'm creating an AWS Lambda function for accessing RDS database. I wrote the code inline in the aws console. I did not zip and upload anything. i hit deploy and test. My code fails at the first row:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
```

The error message I got is
"errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'mysql2' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",

Locally, I have the mysql2 installed.

How can I make sure the mysql2 is available for deploying lambda function?

Comment: See [Runtime dependencies in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure the mysql2 is available for deploying lambda function?

You need to put your `node_modules` either into the zip file with your lambda code, or into a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html). The latter is useful if you have lots of lambdas sharing the same dependency.

To put it into the zip file, just package your `node_modules` folder along with your handler code. `node_modules` has to be at the root of the virtual directory in the zip file.

To put it into the layer, place it under `nodejs/node_modules` insize the zip file for the layer. Inside your Lambda container, it will get mounted under `/opt/nodejs/node_modules`. The Lambda runtime is already set up to look for the dependencies under this path.

If any of your modules use native bindings, you should be also be mindful of binary compatilibity (make sure that the native bindings are compiled for the right architecture and linked with libraries provided by the Lambda runtime). However, mysql2 doesn't use native bindings.